# Inheriting from weakly linked iOS classes or classes not in deployment target iOS version

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, properties, weak-linking

My code has a class in it (let's call it myRefLib) that inherits from UIReferenceLibraryViewController (part of UIKit Framework) which is a class that is only available in iOS 5 and above.  I would like to have a deployment target of iOS 3.2.

If i was just creating an instance of the UIReferenceLibraryViewController, I understand I can use a base SDK of 5 and then test if the class exists with [UIReferenceLibraryViewController class] before running any code that includes it.  But how do I do it if I'm inheriting from the class?

The issue is that I have to #include the inheriting class myRefLib for the parts of my code that will use it - but there is no way to conditionally do that at runtime.  Alternatively there is also no way of runtime conditionally inheriting from UIReferenceLibraryViewController in myRefLib.  I'd also like to make an instance of myRefLib a property of another class - again, how can I do that runtime conditionally?

Any help much appreciated ...

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you have know what you're going to do when running on the earlier OS.  Basically, you have to write your code as though you were building against the iOS 3.2 SDK.  Only then can you add optional enhancements using the newer features.

Starting with the easiest thing: you don't need a declaration of a class interface in order to declare variables, including instance variables, as pointers to that class.  You just need a forward declaration:

```
@class SomeClass;
SomeClass* foo;
```

Next, there should be no problem with importing a header which defines your class. That's a compile-time thing, which you seem to think is a problem, but which means it's not affected by the runtime environment. It will compile because you're building against the iOS 5.0 SDK.

The thing you have to be careful of is to not **use** the class if it's not available. You already know how to check that: test if `[SomeClass class]` returns `Nil`. If it does, don't instantiate your custom subclass.

Finally, you mention "runtime conditionally inheriting from UIReferenceLibraryViewController in myRefLib". Why do you think you need to do that? If `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` is not available, then it doesn't make much sense to want to use `myRefLib` which subclasses it. If you have some alternative implementation in mind that doesn't depend on `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`, then make a separate class. Then conditionally pick between `myRefLib` and this other class depending on availability.

Comment: Thanks Ken. The only reason I brought up conditional inheritance was as an alternative if there was no solution to the #include issue. You post also led me here, which goes into some details: http://www.marco.org/2010/11/22/supporting-older-versions-of-ios-while-using-new-apis ... shows it's OK to subclass, include and point to the missing class, provided certain conditions are met and provided you don't instantiate.

Comment: Oh, also the class method [UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:str] returns nil without crashing if the UIReferenceLibraryViewController class does not exist. So, in the case of this specific class, if you were already checking the word exists before instantiating (and provided the conditions above are met), it looks like there is no need to change any code for older versions. Though I suppose that behavior of dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm is not guaranteed to continue in future iOS versions - so best to add a [UIReferenceLibraryViewController class] check, too.